# Spark Multiple catalog support

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to add multiple spark catalog in spark 3.x and I have a question: Does spark support a feature that allows us to use multiple catalog managed by namespace like this:

```
spark.sql.catalog.<ns1>.conf1=...
spark.sql.catalog.<ns1>.conf2=...
spark.sql.catalog.<ns2>.conf1=...
spark.sql.catalog.<ns2>.conf2=...
```

As the above config, we can use 2 catalog like this:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM ns1.db1.table1") // Load data from table1 in db1 of catalog ns1
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM ns2.db2.table2") // Load data from table2 in db2 of catalog ns2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could add the additional catalog by

```
spark.sql.catalog.catalog1=...
spark.sql.catalog.catalog1.type=...
spark.sql.catalog.catalog1.warehouse=...
spark.sql.catalog.catalog2=...
spark.sql.catalog.catalog2.type=...
spark.sql.catalog.catalog2.warehouse=...
```

The `catalog1` and `catalog2` itself is the catalog name and so it can be used as you mentioned.

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM catalog1.db1.table1")
```

Comment: Can you explain it more detail? For example, how can I use multiple hive metastore as catalogs?

Comment: @NgọcSơnĐỗ were you able to use multiple hive metastore as catalogs?